# Run project or .cs file developed on other computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have several projects and .cs files developed on other computer.

How can I run all of them on different computer? What if I already have project with same name on it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how do you want to run them ? Open in visual studio ? through tthe command prompt?

Comment: Yes, in VisualStudio, and ie. to continue development of them.

Comment: Just open it, it doesn't matter if it the project with the same name exists on the system, as long as their location on hard drive is different. You can open them and continue building on them.

Comment: If you have your projects in a separate folder, you are good to go. You need not worry if the same project already exists, they will both show up in your recent projects list.

Comment: check out codeplex.com or work on your projects on a "web" drive like DropBox (I'm not pushing certain services or brands, I'm only giving examples)
For svn you could try RiouxSVN.com

Comment: Have you tried it? what problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the whole directory of the solution and open in visual studio?  Projects aren't linked to the machine they are running on. The only issue you might have is with installed components (like crystal reports or devexpress) or Linked Projects with an absolute location (basically stuff which doesn't reside the the solutions directory)

If you already have projects (with different paths) but with the same name, just make sure you open the right one. if the paths are the same well just like with files you'll overwrite them.

There isn't anything special about source code, it's just files on the machine